# SELECT tableA.id, tableB.id FROM tableA, tableB WHERE tableA.id *= tableB.id. this query is sql server 2005 and i need sql server 2016?

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT  tableA.id, tableB.id  FROM    tableA, tableB WHERE   tableA.id *= tableB.id.
```

This query is **sql server 2005** and I need **sql server 2016**. I need to do a `LEFT` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and for that, need to use the "new" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to do a LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN and for that, need to use the
> "new" syntax.

try this

```
SELECT  A.id, B.id  
FROM    tableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.id
```

Comment: self explanatory, no? `I need to do a LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN and for that, need to use the "new" syntax`